# Bertrand's ballot theorem proof by induction

Tags: probability

I'm looking at the inductive proof here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_ballot_theorem

And I don't understand this part:

```
Assume it is true both when p = a − 1 and q = b, and when p = a and q = b−1, with a > b > 0. Then considering the case with p = a and q = b, the last vote counted is either for the first candidate with probability a/(a + b), or for the second with probability b/(a + b).
```

Why the probability of the last vote is a/(a+b) (or b/(a+b))... ? 
I understand that there are (a+b) total votes, but I don't understand the calculation to get for a/(a+b) . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This proof relies on the induction hypothesis on two variables. We are assuming that the formula is true for the case when either $(p,q) = (a-1, b)$ or $(p,q) = (a,b-1)$. We want to prove that when the formula is true for these cases, it will also be true for the case $(p,q) = (a,b)$.

We can obtain the case $(p,q) = (a,b)$ in two possible ways. This is done by considering the last vote that was cast. It will either be a vote for the first candidate or for the second.

If it was for the first candidate then the state must have changed from $(a-1,b)$ to $(a,b)$. If it was for the second candidate, then the state changed from $(a,b-1)$ to $(a,b)$.

The probability of the first candidate being ahead at the end, given the state $(a,b)$, is calculated as a weighted combination of the probabilities that are calculated from formula for states $(a-1,b)$ and $(a,b-1)$.

Let $f$ denote the expression given by the formula, we have

$$
f(a-1,b) = \frac{a-1-b}{a-1+b} \textrm{  and  } 
f(a,b-1) = \frac{a - (b - 1)}{a + b -1}
$$

The weights used for the combination depend on the probability of the last vote cast being for the first candidate ($\frac{a}{a+b}$) or for the second candidate ($\frac{b}{a+b}$).

So the inductive step given in the proof is the expression

$$
f(a,b) = P(\textrm{last vote for first}) \times f(a-1,b)
+ P(\textrm{last vote for second}) \times f(a,b-1)
$$

Substituting the probabilities and expressions above gives
$$
f(a,b) = 
\left[\frac{a}{a+b} \right]
\, \left[ \frac{a-1-b}{a-1+b} \right]
+ 
\left[ \frac{b}{a+b} \right] \, 
\left[ \frac{a - (b - 1)}{a + b -1} \right]
$$

After simplifying, they show this leads to 
$$
f(a,b) = \frac{a-b}{a+b}
$$
which demonstrates the step part of the inductive proof.

Together with the first part, this completes the proof.

The step part of the induction estimates the value of $f(a,b)$ using values of $f(a-1,b)$ and $f(a,b-1)$. If we know that $a$ votes were cast for the first candidate and $b$ for the second then we can use the proportions $a/(a+b)$ and $b/(a+b)$ to represents the chances of any individual vote for the first and second candidates respectively. In the step of collecting one more vote to go from $a+b-1$ votes to $a+b$ votes, the candidate receiving the new vote determines the relative contributions of $f(a-1,b)$ and $f(a,b-1)$ towards the value of $f(a,b)$. If $a$ is significantly greater than $b$ then $f(a-1,b)$ will receive a greater weight because is more likely that we have made a transition from $(a-1,b)$ to $(a,b)$ than a transition from $(a,b-1)$ from $(a,b)$.

We can think of all the combinations (states) of $(a,b)$ as points on a lattice with horizontal and vertical lines joining adjacent points. Moving horizontally, say, can represent a vote cast for the first candidate and moving vertically can represent a vote for the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understood everything you wrote, except the part of "The weights used for the combination depend on the probability of the last vote cast being for the first candidate (a/a+b) or for the second candidate (b/a+b)."

I understand that those are the lasts votes but don't understand why those are the probabilities.

If I have for example 10 balls, 7 red and 3 blue, then it's 7/10 to choose red one and 3/10 to choose blue one, but I see it as a different problem.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to address this in an edit to the answer. Hopefully it clarifies.